# mongodb installed in azure ubuntu cannot connect

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, azure

I am trying to connect to a mongodb database I installed on an Ubuntu VM on Microsoft Azure. I did the following:

1. Created virtual machine.
2. sudo apt-get mongodb (I connected to the VM with ssh).
3. Created an Endpoint on the Azure Management Portal with both public and private ports set to 27017.
4. When connected via ssh, running the mongo command allows me to view and access the data stored in the mongodb, but when done remotely, the connection fails with:

   Sat Oct 11 13:34:08.378 JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to server   xxxxxx.cloudapp.net:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L114

I think I am missing something pretty basic here. Hopefully someone out there can help me?

Comment: Did you start the service? ```sudo service mongod start```

Comment: my two questions: a) can you connect local (you do ssh, and then from the shell try to connect to mongodb)? b) can you connect to anyother service in that VM (eg. http server, ftp, etc).

Comment: While I haven't done sudo service commands, I can see mongod running when I do  ps -e, also the local mongo shell, ("mongo" command allows me connect and do queries. I have not tried http, but I did try a custom node.js app running on port 3000. Only by adding the endpoint was enough to allow me to connect.

Comment: You should verify if the http interface is accessible with : http://localhost:28017 . If you are not able to access then verify if if any other service on that machine is accessible from the remote machine. If not that there is something which is blocking the remote machine from accessing services on your hosted ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like mongo has some problems when connecting with a regular string. Might be related to this [JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3254).

Try to connect with the following syntax: `mongo -u <user> -p <password> hostIP:port/db`

Answer (score 2):

make sure you unbind the IP for connecting remotely to it by editing:

```
sudo vi /etc/mongod.conf
```

Set bind_ip=0.0.0.0

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

to test, use: `mongo SERVER-IP:27017/DBNAME -u DBUser -p DBPass